# Bootstrap-Vue B-Form-Checkbox not reacting to clicks even though it is enabled

Tags: bootstrap-vue

My bootstrap-vue `b-form-checkbox` is not reacting to clicks and does not change value.

Use of `b-form-checkbox` in template:

```
<b-form-checkbox
    v-model="showArchived"
    > 
    Show archived reports
</b-form-checkbox>
```

Binded property in the script:

```
data() {
    return {
            showArchived: false
        };
},
```

What can be the problem? I tried setting `disabled` to `false` (didn't help, setting it to `true` does change styling, so I conclude the checkbox is enabled by default as it should), tried adding `id` or `name` properties, but it didn't help either. It's the only checkbox in the component.

Comment: The code is correct you've pasted is correct, so there must be something outside of that conflicting. Try inspecting the DOM to see if anything is placed on-top of the checkbox that would block you from clicking it.

Comment: It does not seem like anything is on top. When I click on the checkbox with the elements inspector in the DOM the checkbox' label's `::after == $0` line gets highlighted. Can the checkbox be covered by its own label? Also, while I'm keeping the mouse button pressed on the checkbox (the white square), the checkbox'  color changes from white to skyblue which kind of suggest it does know it is being pressed?

Comment: Yeah, the highlighting would suggest it's being pressed. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the console.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to try and create a reproduction of the issue. You can use codepen or codesandbox. You can export a template to either on the BootstrapVue [playground](https://bootstrap-vue.org/play)

Comment: I made some progress - the problem seems to be caused by the fact that one of parent elements has `@click.stop.prevent` (which is necessary for other reasons). If I remove it - the checkbox starts reacting. I don't understand why this would be a problem, there are other clickable items in that parent and they do react to clicks just fine. The `@click.stop.prevent` should be verified from child to parent not the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause by one of parent components having `@click.prevent`. Removing `prevent` made the checkbox reactive again.